# Webpack makes a folder and a file the same name

Tags: webpack

Webpack makes a folder and a file with the same name. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
.
└── main.js
    └── main.js
```

In package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output-path ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  }
```

Comment: Tip: always provide a minimal reproducible example.